# Microsoft Edge Refresh button does not execute the onLoad java script code

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, microsoft-edge

I have the following simple java script code which does not execute when I press the Refresh button in Microsoft Edge. None of the 3 alerts execute at refresh. It works well with Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
    alert('jQuery');
  });
  function func() {
    alert('func');
  }
  function load() {
    alert('load');
  }
  window.onload = load();
  func();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This code can be put in an HTML file (test.html).

Why does this happen? Thank you.

Comment: You're not returning a function to execute from `load`.

Comment: `window.onload = load()` is not the same as `window.onload = load`. It doesn't work like you think it does on Chrome either.

Comment: Something really strange happened. I just tried again with window.onload = load(); and with window.onload = load; and both worked fine. Yesterday none of the 3 alerts was executed after pressing Refresh. Now all 3 works well in both scenarios (window.onload = load();/window.onload = load;).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `window.addEventListener("load", load, false);`. Sometimes, if one thing doesn't work, another will.

Comment: This one works as well. As I said above, now all methods of executing something at load time work fine.